# Type error when modifying a value of an object (accessed via index) that implements an interface

Tags: typescript

I'm a beginner in TypeScript, and I'm not sure why TS is complaining on the left hand side of the = sign.

```
const nonMandatoryFields = [
    'address',
    'mobilePhone',
    'postCode',
    'state',
    'suburb',
    'testMode',
];

interface XeroClientData {
    address: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    suburb: string;
    postCode: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    mobilePhone: string;
    email: string;
    recordId: string;
    testMode: boolean;
}

const sanitiseFields = (fields: XeroClientData) => {
    for (const key of nonMandatoryFields) {
        // Error on the left hand side
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type 
        // because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'XeroClientData'
        fields[key] = fields[key as keyof XeroClientData]
            ? fields[key as keyof XeroClientData]
            : '';
    }

    return fields;
};
```

As you can see, I've tried the `keyof` operator and it worked fine on the right side.

If somebody could please point me to a reference doc or point out the problem - would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

---

EDIT: Have managed to fix the issue thanks to @jcalz (BIG THANKS!). See below:

```
const nonMandatoryFields = [
    'address',
    'mobilePhone',
    'postCode',
    'state',
    'suburb',
] as const;

type NonMandatoryField = typeof nonMandatoryFields[number];

interface XeroClientData {
    address: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    suburb: string;
    postCode: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
    mobilePhone: string;
    email: string;
    recordId: string;
    testMode?: boolean; // optional property
}

const sanitiseFields = (fields: XeroClientData) => {
    nonMandatoryFields.forEach(<K extends NonMandatoryField>(key: K) => {
        fields[key] = fields[key] ? fields[key] : '';
    });
    return fields;
};
```

Comment: Can you share a playground link with a little more of code please?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now I get errors almost certainly unrelated to your question; my IDE has no idea what `SomeInterface` and `noMandatoryFields` are, so it's hard to know how to advise you.  If you do make such an [edit] and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment so that I'm notified.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much - apologies I'm still learning how to navigate SO. I've updated the above to include concrete values.

Comment: Well, in trying to fix it (see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp8Lzm)) I hit the issue where you are possibly assigning `""` to a `boolean` property.  That's an error for a good reason.  What are you actually trying to do there?

Comment: Oh - I missed that. of course cant assign "" to a boolean... - my goal was to assign an empty string for the fields in nonMandatoryFields that have a null or undefined value.

Comment: If you don't mention @jcalz then I am not notified. It is a coincidence that I still had this tab open.  How would you like to proceed here, then?

Comment: @jcalz -  I probably would just remove the boolean field to keep it simple and follow your solution in the playground. Or is there another workaround?

Comment: If you [edit] the example to remove the boolean property then I can possibly present a better solution.

Comment: You're new to SO, right?  If you want to answer your own question you can, but it should be as an answer post and not as an edit to the question.  But I am ready to post an answer which is essentially just doing the const assertion; you don't need to refactor to a generic callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `nonMandatoryFields` all accept `string` types (so the default value of `""` is appropriate) like this:

```
const nonMandatoryFields = [
  'address',
  'mobilePhone',
  'postCode',
  'state',
  'suburb',
];
```

If so, then you need to make sure that the compiler keeps track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the strings in that array.  Right now the compiler infers that `nonMandatoryFields` is of type `string[]`, which is too wide for it to be happy with `fields[key]` (because `key` could be any `string` for all it knows).

The easiest way to do this is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializer, like this:

```
const nonMandatoryFields = [
  'address',
  'mobilePhone',
  'postCode',
  'state',
  'suburb',
] as const;
```

Now the type of `nonMandatoryFields` is

```
// const nonMandatoryFields: readonly ["address", "mobilePhone", 
//   "postCode", "state", "suburb"];
```

so the compiler knows exactly which values are present (and also their locations within the array, although this is not needed for your code to work).

Once you do this, everything starts working:

```
const sanitiseFields = (fields: XeroClientData) => {
  for (const key of nonMandatoryFields) {
    fields[key] = fields[key] ? fields[key] : ''; // okay
  }
  return fields;
};
```

The compiler knows that each `key` is a key of `XeroClientData` which accepts a `string`.  Note that you can simplify `x ? x : y` to `x || y` (unless evaluating `x` twice somehow affect things), so you can rewrite this as

```
const sanitiseFields = (fields: XeroClientData) => {
  for (const key of nonMandatoryFields) {
    fields[key] = fields[key] || ''; // okay
  }
  return fields;
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBG4FkCGYAmSogE4E8BiAlgKYA2qEMAvDANoCwAUDDAORKqpZEQQsA0jZiwC2IAEYESRAAoALcEX6DWABxDQAwiFSKBTVtAy7lLCAFcxZrGKUMAujCQVQkKAG5GAek8wX0OIgo6Ji4hKTkAFwwXOzgJDi0AETsnNwQiXwwiaISUnIKGVlqmtpEhYmGUGWZFRZWYol2HgyMBGBVWABmSMBEMAAaRFggGiTE7QAiGEgwAN7KKVw8UdBYbQDmzcydBFjQAHJIwkQrUGtgm8okTlCHx6fnl-rmltYPG1swxVBaOu8Xn0qJxgqw+ylAZnauH+T2YOUkMnkYGBoIByiIwiQkhhny4oCwqAAkqgccoqtAEKUAPxRMQgEBSFBuGDeGAgFRQAjgJAkL7DFRDKA4RgAX0YjD8sAgKAInIgRDCZAo1AAFDtwhAooNhqNxlAplAkABKKgAPjmyk62BgKslMAA1kQEiBOgEwMg0BhsPhiEqTfN9MxWeqlTRHTgHNQQ+Qw06HFSYNGILGIzAoiwWJ9tr6Y+HI4mc8m8zAAD4l1iZ5Ri-RcKBWMAFjXNEVuIA)